# Vertical bar with appropriate length

Tags: math-mode

I have a scenario in which I need to create a vertical bar that its size is in the length of 3 rows.

My code is:

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x = 2t + 1\\
y = t + 2\\
z = 3
\end{cases}
 & \Bigg | \quad t\in \mathbb R
\end{align*}
```

I'm familiar with the possibility to set its size in centimetres.
Though I prefer to use something similar to `\middle`.
Problem is that in this case, I don't have `\right` and `\left`, so that `\middle` is meaningless (and yield an error).

Note: I'm using the TexMaths plugin of LibreOffice, which uses the standard latex program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\vphantom` of the `cases` environment to adjust the size of `\left` (or `\right`) to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \begin{cases}
    x = 2t + 1 \\
    y = t + 2 \\
    z = 3
  \end{cases}
  & \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \vphantom{\begin{cases}
    x = 2t + 1 \\
    y = t + 2 \\
    z = 3
  \end{cases}}\right| \quad t \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I've just duplicated the `cases` inside a `\vphantom` (zero-width `\phantom`) and corrected for the `\left.` "null" delimiter. Of course, it's not really all than necessary to use `align*` as there's no multiline equation alignment required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[
  \left.\begin{cases}
    x = 2t + 1 \\
    y = t + 2 \\
    z = 3
  \end{cases}
  \right| \quad t \in \mathbb{R}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer the 2nd solution - it's neat. Though I didn't use the enclosing `\[` and `\]` and it worked splendidly. Why do we need them?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `align`; the `cases` environment is just a `matrix` with an increased `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{matrix}
    x = 2t + 1 \\
    y = t + 2 \\
    z = 3
\end{matrix}
\quad
\right| \quad t \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Defining an environment is better, of course:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{pcases}{m}% cases with a parameter condition
 {\env@cases}
 {\endarray\right|\quad#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pcases}{t\in\mathbb{R}}
    x = 2t + 1 \\
    y = t + 2 \\
    z = 3
\end{pcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the `empheq` package (which loads `mathtools`, hence `amsmath`). Here are two solutions:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace, right=\enspace\empheqrvert\enspace t\in\mathbb R]{align*}
  x & = 2t + 1\\
  y & = t + 2\\
  z & = 3
\end{empheq}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{empheq}[right=\enspace\empheqrvert\enspace t\in\mathbb R]{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  x = 2t + 1\\
  y = t + 2\\
  z = 3\end{cases}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]